# Insert object icon missing in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, embedding, microsoft-visio-2003

In the process of creating a flowchart in Visio, I've added some Word documents (*.doc) as embedded objects.  I choose Insert->Object, Create from File, and then Display as icon.

Yesterday, I added three Word docs with no issues.  today, as I add another, I'm no longer able to see the icon for the file.  Even when I choose the icon in the picker, and type a custom name for the object, an "invisible" icon gets embedded.

Here's one from yesterday:
[image]

Here's today:
[image][image]

I've tried moving the shape to the foreground or background, starting with a fresh VSD, and even rebooting, with no success.  I'm using Word 2007 and Visio 2003.

Any idea what's going on?